# Как заставить картинки грузиться последовательно?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, html5

Стоит задача вывести все картинки из папки на веб-страницу, но так, чтобы картинки не все сразу грузились. Допустим у пользователя медленный интернет, тогда чтобы посмотреть хотя бы одну картинку, ему потребуется дождаться загрузки всех картинок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю, что нужно как-то отслеживать статус картинки и после ее загрузки догружать следующую. Подскажите пожалуйста каким методом можно достичь поставленный задачи (Html, JS, Php, Python??).

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: jQuery в проекте испозуете?

Comment: Можно. Главное, чтобы скорость была максимальная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ без необходимости вручную менять разметку:
Ищем все элементы `img` в документе ➝ У каждого из них (кроме первого) переносим `src` в data-атрибут, туда же сохраняем индекс `img` в DOM ➝ При успешной загрузке изображения (при событии `load`), у следующего `img` присваиваем значение `src` обратно, запуская его загрузку.
Просто и эффективно.

```js
var imgs; 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img'); 
  for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].dataset.idx = i; 
    imgs[i].addEventListener('load', onImageLoad); 
    if (!i)      // не мешаем загрузке первого изображения
      continue; 
    imgs[i].dataset.src = imgs[i].src; 
    imgs[i].src = ''; 
  }
}); 

function onImageLoad() {
  console.clear(); 
  console.log(`Изображение ${+this.dataset.idx + 1} загружено.`); 
  let nextImg = imgs[+this.dataset.idx + 1]; 
  if (nextImg)
    nextImg.src = nextImg.dataset.src + '&' + +Date.now(); 
  else
    imgs = null; 
  // подчищаем за собой 
  delete this.dataset.src; 
  delete this.dataset.idx; 
  this.removeEventListener('load', onImageLoad); 
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
  display: flex; height: calc(100vh - 16px); 
  justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; 
}

img { flex: 0 0; width: calc(20% - 5px); min-width: calc(20% - 5px); }
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/1024/?random">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/1024/?random">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/1024/?random">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/1024/?random">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/1024/?random">
```

В примере я добавляю к `src` числовое значение даты, чтобы обойти неправильную загрузку изображений из-за кэширования браузером. Если не добавлять - все 5 изображений загрузятся из одного URL (сервис picsum.photos делает рерайт адреса при параметре `?random`, но браузер-то об этом не знает).

Comment: Логика в принципе понятна. Но мне нужно выгрузить не рандомные картинки, а те, которые там прописанные.

Допустим у меня так будет:
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/1024/img01.jpg">

Comment: @ДанилЛукьяненко, а что Вам мешает прописать в HTML пути к вашим картинкам? :) Скрипту совершенно все равно, какие `href` у элементов. Если беспокоитесь о добавлении даты к пути (что совершенно не мешает серверам отдавать файлы картинок), просто уберите эту часть строки: `+ '&' + +Date.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Если картинок немного, то можно на каждую картинку создать файл .js, задав для него атрибут defer. Соответственно, контент вереницы .js-файлов будет загружаться постепенно, в порядковой очереди. Позволю заметить ещё раз, что для каждой картинки нужно создать отдельный .js-файл. Поскольку в редакторе нет возможности создавать несколько вкладок с .js-файлами, то содержимое 3 .js-файлов поместил вместе, для наглядности. Подробнее здесь - https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script

```js
function f1(){
    var out = document.getElementById('out');
    var img = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-345/512/Bussines-256.png";
    var away = '<img src="' + img + '">';
    out.innerHTML += away + '<br>';
}
f1();
function f2(){
    var out = document.getElementById('out');
        var img = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-345/512/Rocket-256.png";
    var away = '<img src="' + img + '">';
    out.innerHTML += away + '<br>';
}
f2();
function f3(){
    var out = document.getElementById('out');
    var img = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-345/512/Moneyidea-256.png";
    var away = '<img src="' + img + '">';
    out.innerHTML += away + '<br>';
}
f3();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Отправка форм AJAX</title>
 <script src="one.js" defer></script>
 <script src="two.js" defer></script>
 <script src="three.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="out"></p>
</body>
</html>
```